# Loading a UITableViewCell with a NSOperationQueue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsoperationqueue

Hi guys I have an UITableView that loads precomputed cells from NSMutableArray. I want to use NSOperationQueue or PerformSelectorOnMainThread to update the user interface to enable smooth scrolling but i get an error... this is my code...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  //queue is being initialized in viewDidLoad          
  [queue addOperationWithBlock:^ {
      [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {
          NSLog(@"Updating...");      
          return [self.CellObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];          
          //if you remove the line above with the return, NSOperationQueue will work but I need the above line to load the cell.
      }];
  }];
}
```

Is there a way to make it work? Any help appreciated!

Comment: The error is that the block returns void not UITableViewCell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simple ...

```
return [self.CellObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

...?

It's a mess. Why do you have two calls to `addOperationWithBlock:`? And also your `return` statement has nothing to do with return value of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. It's return value of your block, so, it will never work.

What's your error? I assume it's about incompatible block pointer, because it expects `void(^)(void)` and you're trying to send `UITableViewCell *(^)(void)`.

Blocks are not gonna help you there. If you have precomputed cells in `CellObjects`, just use only the `return self.CellObjects[indexPath.row];` line.

Also don't use property names like `CellObjects`. Should be named `cellObjects`. Check the case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yeah it tells me that the return is void not UITableViewCell. I have the cell precomputed but still there is a slight lag on scrolling when a new cell comes into the uitableview. I want to fix this slight lag issue. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @stefanosn simply offsetting the returning of the tableViewCell is not the answer here. If it's stalling as it comes into view then you need to optimise your drawing, or cell reuse pattern. Drawing will always be done on the main thread. Run it in instruments, see where it's spending it's time.

Comment: @Jessedc: I think this is it the drawing. I am going to see this WWDC 2012: Session 211 - Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS maybe it will help me draw the cell faster somehow...if anyone had seen it let me know.

Comment: i was at the session when it was presented. its a good session

Comment: Guys i have put the code return [self.CellObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 but it seems that the uitableview is leaking...and my app crashes after many loads although i do [CellObjects removeAllObjects]; [mytable reloaddata]; any suggestions...?

Comment: Ok guys these two lines crashed my app i had them into cellForRowAtIndexPath: of the tableView: my fault...hope this helps someone...   [cell initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];      
[cell.contentView initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];

Comment: Guys this return [self.CellObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; is not working i get memory warnings and the app crashes after a few loads although i release the cell objects every 20 objects...

Answer (score 0):

Offsetting your cell retrieval in that way is not going to give you any advantage. You need to compute your cell height/size/content prior to your UITableView instance asking for cells.

UITableView is expecting a UITableViewCell to be returned from that delegate callback on the 
main thread.

A better idea would be to place the computation on other threads if they require time and their on completion you can call back to your UITableView to `reloadData`.